# Error: undefined is not a function react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation

I am writing my 1st React-native application and I got the below error message on executing code,

[image]

App.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Login from './App/components/Login.js';

const Application = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Login },
}, {
    navigationOptions: {
      header: false,
    }
  });

export default class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
       <Application />
    );
  }
}
```

Login.js:

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import{
    View,
    Text,
    Stylesheet
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

export default class Login extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Text>Test</Text>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of `react-navigation` are you using?

Comment: @Andrew How to check that? because I simply run command `npn install --save react-navigation`. I installed it 1Hr ago. means it is up-to-date.

Comment: Then your issue is that you are following an old tutorial because the `StackNavigator` was deprecated in v2. As you are likely on v3 then you need to make sure that you are using the correct functions etc, please check the documentation for further details.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for pointing out I am using old tutorial. I'll use latest from now. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to export `createAppContainer` and also `StackNavigator` is deprecated use `createStackNavigator`
Try this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import Login from './App/components/Login.js';

const Application = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Login },
}, {
    navigationOptions: {
      header: false,
    }
  });

class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
       <Application />
    );
  }
}
export default createAppContainer(Application);
```